# customise Joomla Zoo categories

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I have been asked to make some minor updates to a friends website but it's built in joomla which I have had very limited experience in.

Essentially, I am trying to update the following page:

http://gallery.themontpellier.co.uk/index.php/artisits/artists

Currently, when one selects any of the images it loads up a lightbox function - when one selects any of the titles it directs the user to a new page.

How can I configure the joomla Zoo extension to take the user to the title linked page as opposed to calling the lightbox function when clicking on the image.

Obviously, I know how to do this directly in the html, but do not seem to be able to find the correct place in the joomla management system to make such an update.

Apologies for the simplicity of my question - I have been going round and round in circles in the administration system trying to find where this code is built in!

Thanks for any guidance

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Joomla question but a Zoo question. Zoo is a cck from yootheme.com which features very nice graphics, a very complex hierarchy and very hard to edit code.

Stay with me here, the zoo architecture is strange and complicated but it will ultimately be quite easy to achieve this.

Inside your joomla administrator open the menu item "Components" then Zoo.

From here on you'll need to open the last item in the tab group, the one that features a gear.

This will present you with a list of "applications", you will have to open each to find out which is used for your category display, could be Movie or Product.  It would help to know if you're using the free or the paid version, and which version.

Once you open the application, you'll get a nice list of Types ordered by name in a neat table. Hover over the name and see the fields, this should confirm you're in the right folder.

Now you know what your data type name is.  In the same view as above, to the right of the name, you will see several links, something like:

```
  Movie        Default: Feed | Full | Related | Submission | Teaser
```

Click on Teaser, which is the definition of the layout in the category view.

In the page that opens, you will find an item in the left list with type = image , click the pencil icon next to it (edit element), the last field "Link to element" needs to be changed to true.

This is all you need.

Finally, you have misspelled artisists instead of artists in the category slug (alias) which you can edit in the Zoo "Category" page.